# whatsapp share images + titles problem i want multiple title

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem plaese help me.
My application write is xamarin for android.
I send photos and text but photo multiple , text one.

```
sharingIntent.PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Imageuris.ToArray());
sharingIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "TİTLE");
```

this code is multiple photo but single text.
i want to multiple photo and multiple text.
Help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want share multiple text to WhatsApp,you can do that:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
        .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
        .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
        .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
        .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
        .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
        .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
        .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
        .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s")
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you but i want to share whatsapp.
This not work.Help me please.
(Intent.ExtraText)

Comment: Ok, maybe you can refer to this document. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android?locale=en_US